# pointer-events + opacity on hover css

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity, pointer-events

I'm building a site where a seperate div is on top of another. When you hover over the top div I want it to disapear while you hover over it and you should be able to click it.

I at first thought that

```
opacity: 0;
```

and

```
pointer-evets: none;
```

would do the trick, however, with only opcaity 0; you can't click though the div, and with the pointer-events: none; it doesn't fade.
Anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: Did you try `visibility: hidden;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".parent").click(function () {
    alert("I am in Parent");
  });
  $(".child").click(function (e) {
    alert("I am in Child");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}

.parent {border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; padding: 50px;}
.parent .child {border: 1px solid #ccf; padding: 15px; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear; -o-transition: all 0.5s linear; transition: all 0.5s linear;}

.child:hover {opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<p>Please try clicking on both the boxes. One is parent and the other is child. The child will be clickable even though it is hidden.</p>
```

Please try clicking on both the boxes. One is parent and the other is child. The child will be clickable even though it is hidden.

Comment: Basically that's exactly how my site reacts, But When I click on the child box I'd love to click on the parent box, which is below.

Comment: @Vheanom Just remove `e.stopPropagation();`. See the updated code please.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick, just had some minor problems adjusting the code since im a bit new. Thanks!

Comment: @Vheanom No worries. Welcome! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If a div is on top of another div, it will catch all of the events, even if it's at opacity:0.

You could try `visibility:hidden` instead, since AFAIR this actually removes a div from the layout.

EDIT: "remove from the layout" was a poor choice of words. The commenters are of course right, it's still there.

Comment: No, it won't remove it from the layout.

Comment: It doesn’t remove the `div` from the layout, the `div` still affects the layout, but no pointer event can be triggered on this `div` (i.e. you can click “through” it).

Answer (score 0):

Try `opacity: 0.001;`.

It visually brings the exact same result than `opacity:0;` and has helped me short out similar situations where `pointer-events: none;` didn't work either.